# OledbCommandBuilder Syntax error in insert into Statement c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, oledb

I know this question has been asked a hundred of times and I have looked at them all and don't know what's going wrong.
This is the table in access:

```
tbl_Slip

SlipNo*,
EmpID,
ScaleID,
Month-Year,
RaiseBasic,
OtherDed,
Tax,
Arrears,
Notes,
```

all the fields are integer type except for Month-Year and Notes which are text.

Now the C# Part:
This is the code I use. 
I tried to find out the error so made a button with harcoded values.

(The oledbConnection works fine. I use it to display data on the form)

This function I use to link to tbl_Slip.

```
    private void linkToSlip()
    {
        con.Open();

        string sqlRecords = "Select * FROM tbl_Slip ORDER BY SlipNo";
        SlipDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRecords, con);
        SlipDA.Fill(SlipDS, "Slip");

        // Primary key so DataTable.Rows.Find[] can be used
        SlipDS.Tables["Slip"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { SlipDS.Tables["Slip"].Columns["SlipNo"] };
        maxSlipRows = SlipDS.Tables["Slip"].Rows.Count;

        dataGrid_Slip.DataSource = SlipDS;
        dataGrid_Slip.DataMember = "Slip";

        con.Close();
    }
```

This is the form load part:

```
    private void frm_Slip_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SlipDS = new DataSet();
        createcon();
        linkToSlip();
    }
```

(createcon is the function I use to make the connection withthe database)

This is the button code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommandBuilder saveCB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(SlipDA);

        DataRow dR = SlipDS.Tables["Slip"].NewRow();

        dR[0] = Convert.ToInt32("2");
        dR[1] = Convert.ToInt32("1");
        dR[2] = Convert.ToInt32("1");
        dR[3] = "January-2013";
        dR[4] = Convert.ToInt32("15");
        dR[5] = Convert.ToInt32("20");
        dR[6] = Convert.ToInt32("2");
        dR[7] = Convert.ToInt32("223");
        dR[8] = "notes";

        SlipDS.Tables["Slip"].Rows.Add(dR);
        saveCB.DataAdapter.Update(SlipDS.Tables["Slip"]);
        maxSlipRows++;
    }
```

When I press the button the error given is

**Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

I cannot figure out what is the problem. I checked for duplication, I checked if the data was saved in SlipDS.Tables["Slip"] (IT WAS). I can't think of any thing else.

What is wrong ?

Comment: You do realize that `dR[0] = Convert.ToInt32("2");` is the same as `dr[0] = 2;`, only using more words and run time?

Comment: Yes I do 
But i tried everything that could make it function !!!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Don't use the `OleDbCommandBuilder`. Create an `OleDbCommand` manually as `INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...)` and use a parameterized query. Then, add the parameters appropriately.

You'd have to show us the `INSERT` statement so we can tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: I wrote a simple code to insert values and it worked but can you tell me why my first approach failed. I used Oledbcommandbuilder on other forms and it worked ???

Also why should i use parameters instead of just providing the values within the statement ???

Thank you

Comment: Why use parameters?? Well, type safety, SQL injection, etc... How about using the SO search function to see how to make it work? This question has been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the problem for the invalid command is that your field name has a hyphen in it and that is probably NOT being created properly and is being interpreted as

```
insert into tbl_Slip ( EmpID, ScaleID, Month-Year, ...
```

Bad idea to have columns with spaces and/or hyphens.  Yes, databases allow it, but you don't have to shoot yourself in the foot just because you can.

Comment: You can handle that by setting the column name delimiters like this:         `saveCB.QuotePrefix = "["; cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";`